# Trying to change background image, by clicking on an image, jQuery, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images I photoshopped that are weather icons like a sun, cloud, rainy cloud, etc. On the Site I want to be able to click on them, and change the background image of the site, the Body background.  But it doesn't work, can't click on the image, nothing happens. This is what I have so far, with #skyclear being the image ID, and clearsky being the css styling =>

```
$('body').addClass(bodyClass);

$('#skyclear').on('click', () => {
    bodyClass = 'clearsky'
})
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You need to set the body class inside the function.

Comment: You have to remove clearsky class from body using removeClass() and add the new class using addClass(). Just changing the content of the variable doesnt change the element's class.

Comment: @Natha I'm confused, why would I remove the class I'm adding, then add it? How could I even remove it when it's not even there yet?

Comment: @CalebNorris sorry i meant to remove the old class body had before and then add clearsky.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').addClass(bodyClass);
```

This should be in the onClick function. You should also consider removing any unnecessary classes inside of the onClick as well.

Comment: Like so? const onClick = (e) => {$('body').addClass(bodyClass);
        
    $('#skyclear').on('click', () => {
        bodyClass = 'clearsky'
})}

Comment: look at giolliano's answer

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it like this:

```
$('#skyclear').on('click', function(){
    $('body').addClass('clearsky');
});
```